# MySQL: Avoid having to set a NULL value on an UNIQUE field before updating it

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an SQL table with two fields: `id` and `order`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article (
  `id`        INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order`     INT(11) UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

In this table I have some items:

```
+----+-------+
| id | order |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     0 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  3 |     2 |
|  4 |     3 |
|  5 |     4 |
|  6 |     5 |
|  7 |     6 |
|  8 |     7 |
|  9 |     8 |
| 10 |     9 |
+----+-------+
```

Now I want to change order position of one item: element with id 3 (order position 2) will move into position 6. Thus, the elements between position 4 and 6 (this last one included)
will have to decrease their `order` field.
The result should be this:

```
+----+-------+
| id | order |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     0 |
|  2 |     1 |
|  4 |     2 | ⌉
|  5 |     3 | |
|  6 |     4 | | Updated items
|  7 |     5 | |
|  3 |     6 | ⌋
|  8 |     7 |
|  9 |     8 |
| 10 |     9 |
+----+-------+
```

Of course the first update —update item with id `3` with `order` field `6`— is easy:

```sql
UPDATE article
SET article.order = 6
WHERE id = 1;
```

Then I can decrease the items between positions greater than 2 and lower or euql than 6:

```
UPDATE article
SET article.order = article.order -1
WHERE 
  article.order > 2
  AND
  article.order <= 6
;
```

But here there is a problem: `order` field is `UNIQUE`. So I have to first set it to `NULL` for the item I want to move:

```sql
UPDATE article
SET article.order = NULL
WHERE id = 3;

UPDATE article
SET article.order = article.order -1
WHERE 
  article.order > 2
  AND
  article.order <= 6
;


UPDATE article
SET article.order = 6
WHERE id = 3;
```

Is there a way to avoid setting this `NULL`?
Here is a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=342d714e88e68d3c4c6e0ca1ec8efa6c

Comment: As you can see this is a real pain. Why do yo need that? May be there is a better solution

Comment: Yes, maybe there are other ways. For example, preparing the data beforehand in an array of tuples —left item `id`, right item `order`— and try to update the rows with this data in one pass. But can't see how this can be done.

Comment: Annoyingly even if done in one statement MySQL still complains about the transient violation https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd283c17ac8d1fe95bc2f227f38fd1b0

Comment: Yes, but look at the solution by @LukStorms, quite interesting. EDIT: the mentioned solution also fails on the transient violation

Comment: @MartinSmith: Great, someone else ended up with this issue too... ;) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=816f695aa2f6e47f29bef4dfd09a5141 Though this could be done with some joins and a `CASE` but...

Comment: @EmilleC. - LukStorms's answer is two UPDATE statements, not one. I was trying with one because that would work in SQL Server even though it does not have deferrable constraints. No such luck here though

Comment: Ops, you are right

Comment: You could consider making `order` a decimal rather than integer. Then you just have to set the `order` to  `6.5` and you are good to go with no need to update any additional rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid setting this NULL?

Not in MySQL. The SQL Standard defines the feature of *deferrable constraints* that address this specific issue. Unfortunately, MySQL does not implement this section of SQL Specification. Nulls are your only option here.

Now, when a contraint is marked as deferrable (as in PostgreSQL or Oracle), its validation can be deferred to the end of each SQL statement execution, or even to the end of the whole transaction; that is, its full validation happens only at the time of the `commit`, after all updates have been done and all values would be good again.

As you see, unless you have the option to migrate to PostgreSQL or Oracle (highly unlikely) you are stuck with using nulls.

Comment: I will accept this one, as there is no way to update the `order` field in one pass both for an increasing value —from positions 2 to 9 for example— and decreasing ones —from position 7 to position 3— due to the constraint.

Best solution would probably be to remove the constraint, which will make things easier.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not in 1 update because of the unique key.

But it can be done in 2 updates.

With the help of some variables.
And a descending sort, to get the NULL last.

```
--
-- move id 3 to position 6
--
SET @id := 3;
SET @orig := (select `order` from article where id = @id);
SET @dest := 6;
-- select @id id,@orig orig ,@dest dest;

UPDATE article 
SET `order` = NULL
WHERE id = @id;

UPDATE article 
SET `order` =  
    case 
    when  @orig < @dest and `order` between @orig and @dest 
     then `order` - 1
    when  @orig > @dest and `order` between @dest and @orig 
     then `order` + 1
    when `order` is null then @dest
    else `order`
    end
WHERE (
      `order` is null 
   OR `order` between least(@orig,@dest) and greatest(@dest,@orig)
)
ORDER BY if(@orig>@dest,1,-1)*`order` DESC;
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=462e600641dfc7bed2781102bfb238d3)*

Comment: This is very interesting, didn't think about this. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Actually, this only works without the constraint because you are updating them backwards. If you try to update from item 9 to position 2 it will fail.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. That's because the logic in the case is currently designed with the order-1.

Comment: @EmilleC. Now it works both ways.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask myself whether the unique constraint was actually required?  Is any functionality dependent on the order value being unique?  Is the extra overhead of the constraint necessary?  If not -

```sql
UPDATE `article`
SET `order` = IF(`id` = 3, 6, `order` - 1)
WHERE `order` BETWEEN 2 AND 6;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8b402bdef09f55538493f5bda6e4714f)